# Updating Tracking on Sendport on Biztalk 2020 using REST API

Tags: rest, biztalk, biztalk-2020

We are using Biztalk 2020 and have enabled the REST API to use for our needs.
One of the things we want to do is to script and update the tracking settings on Recieveport, Sendport, Orchestration and pipelines.

Everything works except for Send Port.

Whatever I send (as long as it is in correct format) I get back an error:

> ERROR: Adapter  is not a valid adapter.

Please take note of the extra space between the words "Adapter" and "is" - it seems that there is missing something, like the log has a value that is not filled (empty string).

I have even tried first to get the existing settings by the swagger page (GET):
http://localhost/BizTalkManagementService/SendPorts/portname

And sent it back in the same exact format to (PUT):
http://localhost/BizTalkManagementService/SendPorts/portname

I get the same error message as described above.

Is this perhaps a bug in the API?